# im tryin to import navbar component and used it but still got warn it never used?

Tags: reactjs

im tryin to import navbar component and used it but why it did'nt show up when i used it and still got warn i never used it?

```
//navbar.js
import React from 'react'

export default function navbar() {
return (
<div> this is navbar component</div>
)}


//app.js
import navbar from './component/navbar';

function App() {
return (
<>
<h1>hello</h1>
<navbar />
</>
);}

export default App;


src\App.js
Line 2:8:  'navbar' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change navbar to Navbar

```
//navbar.js

export default function Navbar() {
return (
<div> this is navbar component</div>
)}


//app.js
import Navbar from './component/navbar';

function App() {
return (
<>
<h1>hello</h1>
<Navbar />
</>
);}
```

first character of custom component name must be Uppercase.

and you dont need import react in navbar.js